# How to store panel data in MySQL database (relational schema design)

Tags: database-design

I am trying to upload a couple panel datasets to a MySQL server. But I have a couple issues when it comes to schema design.

How do I create a relational schema and combine these 2 tables together in a MySQL database?

Do I need a Star schema or a Snowflake schema?

**Dataset (1)**: Account profile table, it has multiple clients' information in daily granularity (365 days in total). The example below shows two accounts (`HP` and `KA`) with client `income`, `age` and `gender`. `File Date` is the client account status date.

| Account ID | Income | Age | Gender | File Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HP | 10,000 | 40 | Male | 2019-04-01 |
| HP | 10,000 | 40 | Male | 2019-04-02 |
| HP | 10,000 | 40 | Male | 2019-04-03 |
| HP | 12,000 | 40 | Male | 2019-04-04 |
| KA | 12,000 | 23 | Female | 2019-04-01 |
| KA | 12,000 | 23 | Female | 2019-04-02 |
| KA | 12,000 | 23 | Female | 2019-04-03 |
| KA | 12,000 | 23 | Female | 2019-04-04 |

**Dataset (2)**: Account trading table, it has multiple clients' information in daily granularity. In the example below the first row says account `HP` bought google stock on `2019-06-12` for 500.00 dollars.

| Account ID | Stock ID | Trade Type | Trade Amount | File Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HP | GOOG | Buy | 500.0 | 2019-06-12 |
| HP | APPL | Sell | 600.0 | 2020-03-23 |
| KA | AMZN | Sell | 1000.0 | 2020-07-23 |
| KA | APPL | Sell | 353.0 | 2020-10-13 |
| KA | MSFT | Buy | 400.0 | 2021-02-03 |

Comment: 1) You should store birthdate rather than age in a database.  2) You'll need at least two database tables, Account Profile and Account Trading.  I don't understand what the Income column represents.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc OK, Thanks for your advice. My question focuses on how to deal with repeated record for everyday. Should I create primary key for File date x account ID ?

Comment: I can't answer a question like that unless I understand what each table column represents.  Right now, I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get an explanation, so I'm assuming that income is a synonym for balance and not additional money each day.

I'd start with an Account table

```
Account
-------
Account ID (PK)
Gender
Birthdate
```

And an Account Balance table

```
Account Balance
---------------
Account ID 
Balance Date 
Balance
```

Where the primary key is (Account ID, Balance Date descending).

Finally, we have a Transaction table

```
Transaction
-----------
Transaction ID (PK)
Account ID 
Transaction Date 
Stock ID
Trade Type
Trade Amount
```

With a unique index on (Account ID, Transaction Date descending)

Comment: Thanks very much Gilbert, Could I ask why we need a unique index on Transaction Table? Since we have Transaction ID (PK) already.

Comment: You use the PK to retrieve all or all recent transactions.  You use the unique index to retrieve transactions for a particular account.